# Struct vs int64 value

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit

Assume that this is for a 32-bit application. I have two ID values which together uniquely identify a particular object. Each ID is a plain 32-bit int, so in order to identify any particular object I need to keep both ID values together.

The first solution that comes to mind is to store them is as two separate values, and pass them around in a struct:

```
struct {
    int id1;
    int id2;
};
```

However, it would be nice if I could pass them around as a single value rather than a struct pair, as I did back when there was only a single 32-bit ID value.

So, another idea is to store them as the upper and lower halves of a uint64_t.

My question is, is there any real difference between the two methods? Either way, the same number of bytes are being passed around, but I don't know if there is any special overhead for int64, since the CPU isn't natively handling 64-bit values.

Comment: "*The first solution that comes to mind...*" Solution to what problem?

Comment: A struct *is* a single value. As you say, you have to pass 8 bytes around either way.

Comment: @ildjarn Probably to pass the two IDs around, I guess it's implied from the rest of the question.

Comment: @ildjarn Sorry, updated for clarification. Solution to the issue of keeping two 32-bit values together, but treat them as a single value.

Comment: Based on your needs, you could also define it as a std::pair<int, int> (which I usually typedef to IntPair).  This gives you some predefined operators such as == and <.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't make up your mind, use a union.

Microsoft for example defines a [`LARGE_INTEGER` union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383713.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

The best handling depends on how the entity is handled.  If it is usually/mostly comparisons of the two sub-fields as a unit, then int64 has validity.  If it is often inspecting the sub-fields independently, then the struct is more natural.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason not to use the struct.

Comment: Sure there is. `uint64_t` defines some handy operators such as `==` and `<` that you'd have to generate by hand for the struct.

Comment: @Mark: Good point, but only if those operators have the expected behaviour for Nairou. If he does not want a lexicographic compare, he will need to implement the (in)equality operators anyway and then a simple struct may be more straightforward.

Comment: @MarkRansom: If the OP indicated he wanted them...?